# How to merge multiple imports in scala?

Tags: scala, package, scalameta

Assume I have a library a.com. Everytime and in each file, I need to import a lot of package like

```
import a.com._
import a.com.b._
import a.com.c
import a.com.Implicits._
```

I don't want to write these code every time in each file of 
another project.

Also if I want to change `a.com` to `a.net`, I have to change every file.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Automagic import would be discouraged: increase conflict risk, decrease readability

Answer (score 0):

You can [generate sources](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html)

*build.sbt*

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.13.1",
)

lazy val in = project
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
  )

lazy val out = project
  .settings(
    sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
      Generator.gen(
        inputDir  = sourceDirectory.in(in, Compile).value,
        outputDir = sourceManaged.in(Compile).value
      )
    }.taskValue,

    commonSettings,
  )
```

*project/build.sbt*

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "4.2.3"
```

*project/Generator.scala*

```
import sbt._

object Generator {
  def gen(inputDir: File, outputDir: File): Seq[File] = {
    val finder: PathFinder = inputDir ** "*.scala"

    for(inputFile <- finder.get) yield {
      val inputStr = IO.read(inputFile)
      val outputFile = outputDir / inputFile.toURI.toString.stripPrefix(inputDir.toURI.toString)
      val outputStr = Transformer.transform(inputStr)
      IO.write(outputFile, outputStr)
      outputFile
    }
  }
}
```

*project/Transformer.scala*

```
import scala.meta._

object Transformer {
  def transform(input: String): String = transform(input.parse[Source].get).toString

  def transform(input: Tree): Tree = input match {
    case source"..${List(q"package $eref { ..$stats }")}" =>
      q"""package $eref {
         import a.com._
         import a.com.b._
         import a.com.c
         import a.com.Implicits._
         ..$stats
      }"""
  }
}
```

*in/src/main/scala/com/example/App.scala*

```
package com.example

object App {

}
```

*out/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main/scala/com/example/App.scala* (after `sbt "; project out; clean; compile"`)

```
package com.example
import a.com._
import a.com.b._
import a.com.c
import a.com.Implicits._
object App
```

Comment: I feel code generation is not friendly to IDE. Maybe not the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: @worldterminator Well, I don't insist that this is the best way to solve this problem. Actually I would agree with cchantep's comment. But to clearify, why do you consider code generation not friendly to IDE? I would agree that macros/macro annotations/compiler plugins are not friendly to IDE. But why code generation? I guess IDE indexes scalameta-generated sources well. Or maybe I misunderstand something.

Comment: @worldterminator This is not (deprecated) scalameta macros, this is scalameta code generation.

Comment: Well, I guess that's depends on IDE. Usually when we write code `object App` without writing `importing ...`, I guess IDE won't figure it out that those `import` should be "attached" at the head of the source code.

Comment: I did think out of one way, which is `creating the package object in a.com, use macro or other code generation to alias all types/constructor/constants/implicts into package object`, still not a quite nice method. I only export several things into package object manually