# How to disable compiling some section of code in Scala Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-assembly

I want to disable compiling some section code and system jobs in the Scala Play Framework for example pass a flag at the assembly time jar file to disable compiling some sections.

Comment: What do you mean disable compiling ?! Code have to be compiled if you want to run it afterwards.

Comment: @GaëlJ for example if I want to build two jar files with a source code, but to prevent compiling extra source code, I want to pass a flag or a config in compile time and disable building some section of code.

Comment: Look at SBT submodules then. Each submodule will produce a JAR.

Comment: Can you comment out the section of code that shouldn't be compiled?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Is it possible to comment section of codes in compile time automatically?

Comment: @moeinzargarzadeh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796570/scala-conditional-compilation