# Is it possible to using macro to modify the generated code of structural-typing instance invocation?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, structural-typing, scalameta, semanticdb

For example as the following code:

```
object Test extends App
{
    trait Class
    {
        val f1: Int
    }

    val c = new Class {
        val f1: Int = 1
        val f2: String = "Class"
    }

    println(c.f1)
    println(c.f2)
}
```

I look into the bytecode with a decompiler, and notice that the compile generate a java interface 'Test.Class' as pseudo code:

```
trait Class
{
    val f1: Int
}
```

and a class 'Test$$anon$1' implemeting 'Test.Class', pseudo code as:

```
class Test$$anon$1 extends Class
{
    val f1: Int = 1
    val f2: String = "Class"
}
```

and then the compiler initiaize the variable 'c' as:

```
c = new Test$$anon$1()
```

then calls the member 'f1' as normal invocation:

```
println(c.f1)
```

but it calls 'f2' using reflection:

```
println(reflMethod(c, f2))
```

Here, since the definition of the anonymous class 'Test$$anon$1' is visible in the same scope, is it possible to use macro to change the generated code to invoke 'f2' as normal field avoiding reflection?

I just want to change the invocation code in the same scope, not want to change the reflection code across scopes e.g. structual-typing instance as argument in function call. So I think it is possible in theory. But I am not familiar with scala macro, suggestions and code examples are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Scala macros would have to generate a valid Scala code that could be compiled. What would be the valid Scala code here if not something that has to use reflection?

Comment: Nonetheless I doubt it's possible, but that would not be a good idea and  overengineered. If you don't want structural typing, don't use it (define `f2`, either in `Class` or explicit subtype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros (more precisely, [macro annotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) because [def macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) are irrelevant to this task) are not enough. You want to rewrite not class (trait, object) or its parameter or member but local expressions. You can do this either with [compiler plugin](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/plugins/index.html) (see [also](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/compiler-plugins.html)) at compile time or with [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/) code generation before compile time.

If you choose Scalameta then actually you want to rewrite your expressions semantically rather than syntactically because you want to go from local expression `new Class...` to the definition `trait Class...` and check whether there are proper members there. So you need Scalameta + [SemanticDB](https://scalameta.org/docs/semanticdb/guide.html). More convenient is to use Scalameta + SemanticDB with [Scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/developers/setup.html) (see also section [for users](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/users/installation.html)).

You can create your own rewriting rule. Then you can use it either for rewriting your code in-place or for code generation (see below).

*rules/src/main/scala/MyRule.scala*

```
import scalafix.v1._
import scala.meta._

class MyRule extends SemanticRule("MyRule") {
  override def isRewrite: Boolean = true

  override def description: String = "My Rule"

  override def fix(implicit doc: SemanticDocument): Patch = {
    doc.tree.collect {
      case tree @ q"new { ..$stats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats1 }" =>
        val symbols = stats1.collect {
          case q"..$mods val ..${List(p"$name")}: $tpeopt = $expr" =>
            name.syntax
        }

        val symbols1 = inits.headOption.flatMap(_.symbol.info).flatMap(_.signature match {
          case ClassSignature(type_parameters, parents, self, declarations) =>
            Some(declarations.map(_.symbol.displayName))
          case _ => None
        })

        symbols1 match {
          case None => Patch.empty
          case Some(symbols1) if symbols.forall(symbols1.contains) => Patch.empty
          case _ =>
            val anon = Type.fresh("anon$meta$")
            val tree1 =
              q"""
                class $anon extends ${template"{ ..$stats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats1 }"}
                new ${init"$anon()"}
              """
            Patch.replaceTree(tree, tree1.syntax)
        }
    }.asPatch
  }
}
```

*in/src/main/scala/Test.scala*

```
object Test extends App
{
  trait Class
  {
    val f1: Int
  }

  val c = new Class {
    val f1: Int = 1
    val f2: String = "Class"
  }

  println(c.f1)
  println(c.f2)
}
```

*out/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main/scala/Test.scala* (after `sbt out/compile`)

```
object Test extends App
{
  trait Class
  {
    val f1: Int
  }

  val c = {
  class anon$meta$2 extends Class {
    val f1: Int = 1
    val f2: String = "Class"
  }
  new anon$meta$2()
}

  println(c.f1)
  println(c.f2)
}
```

*build.sbt*

```
name := "scalafix-codegen-demo"

inThisBuild(
  List(
    scalaVersion := "2.13.2",
    addCompilerPlugin(scalafixSemanticdb),
    scalacOptions ++= List(
      "-Yrangepos"
    )
  )
)

lazy val rules = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "ch.epfl.scala" %% "scalafix-core" % "0.9.16"
  )

lazy val in = project

lazy val out = project
  .settings(
    sourceGenerators.in(Compile) += Def.taskDyn {
      val root = baseDirectory.in(ThisBuild).value.toURI.toString
      val from = sourceDirectory.in(in, Compile).value
      val to = sourceManaged.in(Compile).value
      val outFrom = from.toURI.toString.stripSuffix("/").stripPrefix(root)
      val outTo = to.toURI.toString.stripSuffix("/").stripPrefix(root)
      Def.task {
        scalafix
          .in(in, Compile)
//          .toTask(s" ProcedureSyntax --out-from=$outFrom --out-to=$outTo")
          .toTask(s" --rules=file:rules/src/main/scala/MyRule.scala --out-from=$outFrom --out-to=$outTo")
          .value
        (to ** "*.scala").get
      }
    }.taskValue
  )
```

*project/plugins.sbt*

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalafix" % "0.9.16")
```

Other examples:

https://github.com/olafurpg/scalafix-codegen

https://github.com/DmytroMitin/scalafix-codegen

https://github.com/DmytroMitin/scalameta-demo

[Scala conditional compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796570/scala-conditional-compilation)

[Macro annotation to override toString of Scala function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338239/macro-annotation-to-override-tostring-of-scala-function/)

[How to merge multiple imports in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562229/how-to-merge-multiple-imports-in-scala/)

Comment: Thank you very much for comprehensive codes and references! I'll study these meticulously. Hope I can learn more scala skills and work it out.