# scala.meta parent of parent of Defn.Object

Tags: scala, scalameta

Let it be the following hierarchy:

```
object X extends Y{
...
}
trait Y extends Z {
...
}
trait Z {
  def run(): Unit
}
```

I parse the scala file containing the `X` and

I want to know if its parent or grandparent is `Z`.

I can check for parent as follows:
Given that `x: Defn.Object` is the `X` class I parsed,

```
x
.children.collect { case c: Template => c }
.flatMap(p => p.children.collectFirst { case c: Init => c }
```

will give `Y`.

**Question:** Any idea how I can get the parent of the parent of `X` (which is `Z` in the above example) ?

Loading `Y` (the same way I loaded `X`) and finding it's parent doesn't seem like a good idea, since the above is part of a scan procedure where among all files under `src/main/scala` I'm trying to find all classes which extend `Z` and implement `run`, so I don't see an easy and performant way to create a graph with all intermediate classes so as to load them in the right order and check for their parents.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/) to process your sources [not syntactically but semantically](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/developers/before-you-begin.html#is-your-rule-syntactic-or-semantic). Then you need [SemanticDB](https://scalameta.org/docs/semanticdb/guide.html). Probably the most convenient way to work with SemanticDB is [Scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/developers/setup.html)

*rules/src/main/scala/MyRule.scala*

```
import scalafix.v1._
import scala.meta._

class MyRule extends SemanticRule("MyRule") {
  override def isRewrite: Boolean = true
  override def description: String = "My Rule"

  override def fix(implicit doc: SemanticDocument): Patch = {
    doc.tree.traverse {
      case q"""..$mods object $ename extends ${template"""
        { ..$stats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats1 }"""}""" =>
        val initsParents = inits.collect(_.symbol.info.map(_.signature) match {
          case Some(ClassSignature(_, parents, _, _)) => parents
        }).flatten
        println(s"object: $ename, parents: $inits, grand-parents: $initsParents")
    }

    Patch.empty
  }
}
```

*in/src/main/scala/App.scala*

```
object X extends Y{
  override def run(): Unit = ???
}

trait Y extends Z {
}

trait Z {
  def run(): Unit
}
```

*Output of `sbt out/compile`*

```
object: X, parents: List(Y), grand-parents: List(AnyRef, Z)
```

*build.sbt*

```
name := "scalafix-codegen"

inThisBuild(
  List(
    //scalaVersion := "2.13.2",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    addCompilerPlugin(scalafixSemanticdb),
    scalacOptions ++= List(
      "-Yrangepos"
    )
  )
)

lazy val rules = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "ch.epfl.scala" %% "scalafix-core" % "0.9.16",
    organization := "com.example",
    version := "0.1",
  )

lazy val in = project

lazy val out = project
  .settings(    
    sourceGenerators.in(Compile) += Def.taskDyn {
      val root = baseDirectory.in(ThisBuild).value.toURI.toString
      val from = sourceDirectory.in(in, Compile).value
      val to = sourceManaged.in(Compile).value
      val outFrom = from.toURI.toString.stripSuffix("/").stripPrefix(root)
      val outTo = to.toURI.toString.stripSuffix("/").stripPrefix(root)
      Def.task {
        scalafix
          .in(in, Compile)
          .toTask(s" --rules=file:rules/src/main/scala/MyRule.scala --out-from=$outFrom --out-to=$outTo")
          .value
        (to ** "*.scala").get
      }
    }.taskValue
  )
```

*project/plugins.sbt*

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalafix" % "0.9.16")
```

Other examples:

https://github.com/olafurpg/scalafix-codegen (semantic)

https://github.com/DmytroMitin/scalafix-codegen (semantic)

https://github.com/DmytroMitin/scalameta-demo (syntactic)

[Is it possible to using macro to modify the generated code of structural-typing instance invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253920/is-it-possible-to-using-macro-to-modify-the-generated-code-of-structural-typing) (semantic)

[Scala conditional compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796570/scala-conditional-compilation) (syntactic)

[Macro annotation to override toString of Scala function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338239/macro-annotation-to-override-tostring-of-scala-function/) (syntactic)

[How to merge multiple imports in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562229/how-to-merge-multiple-imports-in-scala/) (syntactic)

---

You can avoid Scalafix but then you'll have to work with internals of SemanticDB manually

```
import scala.meta._
import scala.meta.interactive.InteractiveSemanticdb
import scala.meta.internal.semanticdb.{ClassSignature, Range, SymbolInformation, SymbolOccurrence, TypeRef}

val source: String =
  """object X extends Y{
    |  override def run(): Unit = ???
    |}
    |
    |trait Y extends Z
    |
    |trait Z {
    |  def run(): Unit
    |}""".stripMargin

val textDocument = InteractiveSemanticdb.toTextDocument(
  InteractiveSemanticdb.newCompiler(List(
    "-Yrangepos"
  )),
  source
)

implicit class TreeOps(tree: Tree) {
  val occurence: Option[SymbolOccurrence] = {
    val treeRange = Range(tree.pos.startLine, tree.pos.startColumn, tree.pos.endLine, tree.pos.endColumn)
    textDocument.occurrences
      .find(_.range.exists(occurrenceRange => treeRange == occurrenceRange))
  }

  val info: Option[SymbolInformation] = occurence.flatMap(_.symbol.info)
}

implicit class StringOps(symbol: String) {
  val info: Option[SymbolInformation] = textDocument.symbols.find(_.symbol == symbol)
}

source.parse[Source].get.traverse {
  case tree@q"""..$mods object $ename extends ${template"""
    { ..$stats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats1 }"""}""" =>
    val initsParents = inits.collect(_.info.map(_.signature) match {
      case Some(ClassSignature(_, parents, _, _)) =>
        parents.collect {
          case TypeRef(_, symbol, _) => symbol
        }
    }).flatten
    println(s"object = $ename = ${ename.info.map(_.symbol)}, parents = $inits = ${inits.map(_.info.map(_.symbol))}, grand-parents = $initsParents")
}
```

Output:

```
object = X = Some(_empty_/X.), parents = List(Y) = List(Some(_empty_/Y#)), grand-parents = List(scala/AnyRef#, _empty_/Z#)
```

*build.sbt*

```
//scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

lazy val scalametaV = "4.3.18"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % scalametaV,
  "org.scalameta" % "semanticdb-scalac" % scalametaV cross CrossVersion.full
)
```

---

Semanticdb code seems to be working in Scala 3

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/3QQwsDG2Rqm71qa6mMMkTw/36 [[copy](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/b172d806f38892ebc4911210bf65fbe3)] (at Scastie `-Dscala.usejavacp=true` didn't help with `object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found`, so I used Coursier to guarantee that `scala-library` is on path, locally it works without Coursier)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed Dmytro! I found something about scalafix, I was hopping I won't need it.
I'll give it a try and will let you know.

Comment: @Chris Well, important is SemanticDB, not Scalafix. But Scalafix provides convenient API to work with symbols, types etc. (i.e. not only trees, tokens).

Comment: @Chris You can avoid Scalafix but then you'll have to work with SemanticDB manually. See update.

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, I get "cannot resolve symbol info and signature". Using scala 2.11.12. I need this for a devs' utility where all related dependencies can be available only in test scope, so I try to keep build.sbt clean

Comment: @Chris *cannot resolve symbol info and signature* Try Scalafix 0.9.16 and Scala 2.11.12 (or 2.13.2). Just now tried and it worked in both versions. (Just in case sbt 1.3.8.)

Comment: @Chris Anyway have you tried second approach (without Scalafix)?

Comment: @Chris In my first approach (with Scalafix) build.sbt sets up transformation of sources from `in` to `out`. You actually don't need `out`. I guess Scalafix can be run as an app as well (see `scalafix-cli`).

Comment: I tried the second approach (scala 2.11.12, sbt 1.2.8) . For `val initsParents = inits.collect(_.info.map(_.signature) match {` I'm getting 'symbols not found' for `info`&`signature`. for the match block I'm getting 'Required PartialFunction[Any, NotInferedB], Found Function1[Any, Seq[String]]. I was able to find a solution with reflection and meta finally: smth like `instance.info.baseClasses.exists(c => c.info.typeSymbol == baseType)` where `baseType == typeOf[Z].typeSymbol`

Comment: @Chris *I'm getting 'symbols not found' for `info`&`signature`* `scala.meta.Tree#info` is an extension method contributed by implicit class `TreeOps`, `SymbolInformation#signature` is https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.scalameta/trees_2.11/4.3.18/index.html#scala.meta.internal.semanticdb.SymbolInformation@signature:scala.meta.internal.semanticdb.Signature

Comment: @Chris Is it possible that it's just IDE shows `info`&`signature` in red? Did you try `sbt compile`?

Comment: @Chris Also in 2.11 we can't use trailing commas. `"-Yrangepos"` should be instead of `"-Yrangepos",`

Comment: Since Scalameta 4.4.16 `case tree@q"""..$mods object $ename extends ${template"""{ ..$stats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats1 }"""}""" =>` should be replaced with `case tree@q"""..$mods object $ename extends { ..$stats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats1 }""" =>` or `case tree@q"""..$mods object $ename $template""" => template match { case template"{ ..$stats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats1 }" =>` https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/issues/2841

Comment: Semanticdb code seems to be working in Scala 3 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/3QQwsDG2Rqm71qa6mMMkTw/30